# output in tableview should be in each row,i am getting whole response in one row, remaining are blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

output in tableview should be in each row,i am getting whole response in one row, remaining rows are blank .so how to display each row with data from server in uitableview
i get o/p as below in tableview

aa,bbb,cc……

hi,hello,"",…

---

o/p should be as below

aa

hi

---

bbb

hello

---

cc

""

---

this is my response
[{"result":[{"request_id":1,"ticket_number":"P_101","email":"xx","user_id":4,"description":"fjdyhsrwgk","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":2,"ticket_number":"P_102","email":"yyy","user_id":4,"description":"hi","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":3,"ticket_number":"P_103","email":"aaa","user_id":4,"description":"hii","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":4,"ticket_number":"P_104","email":"bbb","user_id":4,"description":"aa..","status":"initiated"}]}]

how to get array of objects in result key

below is code

```
listOfCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

str= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"user_id"];

NSString *strJson=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@",str];
NSString *strlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[strJson length]];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:strlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSData *requestData=[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];

NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"response is %@",strResponse);

dict1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

NSArray *results = [dict1 valueForKey:@"result"];

listOfCustomers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in results)
{
    // Create a new Customer record
    Attributes * newCustomer = [[Attributes alloc] init];
    newCustomer.Customer_ID = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"request_id"];
    newCustomer.Company_Name = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"ticket_number"];
    newCustomer.City = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"email"];
    newCustomer.userId = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"user_id"];
    newCustomer.description = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"description"];
    newCustomer.createdTime = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"createdTime"];
    newCustomer.Status = [oneCustomer valueForKey:@"status"];
    // Add our new Customer record to our NSMutableArray
    [listOfCustomers addObject:newCustomer];
}

[tableVwTotalRequests reloadData];

   }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [listOfCustomers count];
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
}
Attributes* cust = [listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.Company_Name];
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.description];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: what does [listOfCustomers count]; and NSLog(@"%@",cust); returns?

Comment: in [listOfCustomers count] the count is 1

Comment: Can you please write(nslog) what is in your "results" array? It seems that the data you are receiving either have wrong structure, or you are parsing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
}

Attributes* cust = [listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *companyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.Company_Name];
NSArray *companyNames = [companyName componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
cell.textLabel.text = [companyNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.description];
NSArray *descriptions = [description componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: am getting o/p as aa hi remaing rows are blank

Comment: change array count as companyNames or descriptions count in your numberOfRowsInSection method.

Comment: ya i changed but its still my o/p is aa hi in first row ,remaining rows are blank

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your identifier as @"cell", but in your cell initialiser you are passing in the reuse identifier of @"identifier". These should be the same, pass in the variable instead, not the name of the variable as a string.

You are also missing out returning your cell at the end of the method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
Attributes* cust = [listOfCustomers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.Company_Name];
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cust.description];

return cell;
}
```